# Filter object and turn it to Array of Objects with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible that separate object key/values, then filter specific characters, then return a new Array of Objects like this:
`const object =  { id-0: 12, id-1:19 volume-0: 13, volume-1: 10, price-0: 9, price-1: 19 }`

then I need this array:

`const newArray =  [ { id:12 volume: 13, price: 9 }, { id:19 volume: 10, price: 19 } ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the object's entries, reduce them to a Map (see comments in code), and then convert back to an array using `Array.from()`:

```js
const object =  { 'id-0': 12, 'id-1':19, 'volume-0': 13, 'volume-1': 10, 'price-0': 9, 'price-1': 19 }


const result = Array.from(
  Object.entries(object)
    .reduce((acc, [mixedKey, value]) => {
      const [prop, key] = mixedKey.split('-') // get the key and the object's name

      if(!acc.has(key)) acc.set(key, {}) // add new object to the key if none exists

      acc.get(key)[prop] = value // add the prop value to the object

      return acc
    }, new Map())
    .values()
)
  
console.log(result)
```

Using lodash, convert to entries using `_.toPairs()`. Map the array of entries to an array of objects in the shape of `{ 0: { id: 12 }`. Merge all objects to a single object, and convert to an array using `_.values()`:

```js
const { flow, toPairs, map, merge, values } = _

const fn = flow(
  toPairs,
  pairs => map(pairs, ([k, v]) => {
    const [prop, key] = k.split('-')
    
    return { [key]: { [prop]: v }}
  }),
  arr => merge(...arr),
  values
)

const object =  { 'id-0': 12, 'id-1':19, 'volume-0': 13, 'volume-1': 10, 'price-0': 9, 'price-1': 19 }


const result = fn(object)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```